# Bundling js and css in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, web-applications, bundling-and-minification

Is there a way to use bundling in a .NET Core Web Application without node.js (and gulp)?

Official Microsoft documentation goes the way with node/gulp:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Is there a better / lighter way?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice for bundling and minifications suggested by official **Microsoft** is following.

https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification

An open-source bundling and minification solution...
https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Bundler & Minifier extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier), you'll get a file named `bundleconfig.json`, then configure it this way:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/Production/script.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/somelibrary/lib.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/Production/style.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/somelibrary/css/style.css",
    ],
    "minify": { "enabled": true }
  },
]
```

Your files will be bundled on save like in the config file.